# How Can I Display a Message From a ROS2 Publisher In a KivyMD Window?

Tags: python-3.x, kivymd, ros2

What I'm trying to do is essentially take example code to set up and run a Subscriber and Publisher using ROS2 (found [Here](https://docs.ros.org/en/eloquent/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html#write-the-subscriber-node)) and set up the Subscriber python script to use KivyMD to display the Message that it receives from the Publisher python script by updating a simple MDLabel text every second with a variable that the Subscriber callback updates (Note: I currently don't have the code trying to do this yet, as my issue doesn't pertain to it at the moment).

I have no idea what the 'best practice' for going about this would be, since I looked but couldn't find anybody who had done this, aside from some YouTube videos of someone doing it with ROS, but I need to use ROS2, and his tutorial doesn't help with that. So I'm pretty much just winging it.

The problem that I'm finding when trying to do this is that they both *work*, per se, but only one can work at a time, it seems? If in my script, at the end, I run main() (ROS2 code) before MainApp() (KivyMD code), then when I run both the Subscriber and Publisher files in separate terminals, the ROS2 functionality works fine. The Publisher's message reaches the Subscriber. However, the KivyMD window that pops up doesn't populate with the message.

The reverse is true as well, in that if I switch the position of main() and MainApp() and run the KivyMD code before the ROS2 code, then the KivyMD window shows up and populates with the placeholder text (found in .kv file), but the Subscriber doesn't hear the Publisher.

The issue might be obvious but I just can't see it, and I might have been working on this problem for too long to realize it. Can anyone help out?

Here's the python script for the Subscriber Node:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.clock import Clock

global textOutput

textOutput = ""

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_text, 1)

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"

        return Builder.load_file('/home/cobot/dev_ws/src/py_pubsub/py_pubsub/ros_gui.kv')

    def update_text(self, event):
        global textOutput
        self.root.ids.textOutputDisplay.text = textOutput


class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_subscriber')
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            String,
            'topic',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        global textOutput
        textOutput = 'Test'
        self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_subscriber = MinimalSubscriber()
    rclpy.spin(minimal_subscriber)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    # minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    main()

    MainApp().run()
```

And here's the code for the .kv file I'm using for KivyMD:

```
MDScreen:

    MDBoxLayout:
        padding: dp(4), dp(4)
        spacing: dp(4)
        MDLabel:
            id: textOutputDisplay
            text: 'Output Text'
            font_style: 'H1'
            halign: 'center'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem as you, but I was using Tkinter instead of Kivy.
It seems like when you call the `main()` function, the program loops inside the `rclpy.spin()` function, constantly listening for new messages. Thus, your Kivy interface doesn't get updated. 
The other way around, when you exchange the place of the `main()` call and the `MainApp().run()` call. In this case, the Kivy interface starts first and listens for user input or output, hence the thread is blocked and the ROS2-functionality doesn't start.

---

What might help is running both calls parallel in separate threads. 
The easiest way would be to import the `threading` package:

```
import threading
```

Then, you can start a new thread for the ROS2-function and start the Kivy-interface afterwards in the main thread as usual:

```
process_thread = threading.Thread(target=main)
process_thread.start()
MainApp().run()
```

It is important here to set `target=main`, NOT `target=main()`. Otherwise, you would run the `main` function immediately intead of passing it to  `threading.Thread`.
Hope, I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You should import threading method. Here is working code:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from threading import Thread
from example_interfaces.msg import Int64

Window.size = (300, 300)
Window.fullscreen = False

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: 1, 0.627, 0.478, 1

    MDFabButton:
        id: fab_button
        icon: "power"
        style: "large"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .80}
        on_release: app.on_button_press()
    MDLabel:
        id: label_start
        text: "Start"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .58}
        font_style: "Headline"
        role: "small"
    MDLabel:
        text: "Time:"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .45, "center_y": .3}
        font_style: "Headline"
        role: "large"
    MDLabel:
        id: temp_label
        text: "0"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .65, "center_y": .3}
        font_style: "Headline"
        role: "large"
'''

class ROSNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, temp_label):
        super().__init__("graphical_user_interface")
        self.counter_ = 0
        self.temp_label = temp_label
        self.number_subscriber_ = self.create_subscription(Int64, "robot_news", self.callback_number, 10)
        self.get_logger().info("Number counter has been started.")
        self.is_running = False

    def callback_number(self, msg):
        if self.is_running:
            self.counter_ += 1
            if self.temp_label:
                self.temp_label.text = str(self.counter_)

class InterfaceApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ros_node = None
        self.button_state = False

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        self.gui = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.root = self.gui
        return self.gui

    def on_button_press(self):
        self.button_state = not self.button_state
        if self.button_state:
            self.start_ros_node()
            self.root.ids.label_start.text = "Stop"
        else:
            self.stop_ros_node()
            self.root.ids.label_start.text = "Start"

    def start_ros_node(self):
        if self.ros_node is None:
            self.ros_node = ROSNode(self.root.ids.temp_label)
            spin_thread = Thread(target=self.spin_ros_node, args=(self.ros_node,))
            spin_thread.start()
        else:
            self.ros_node.is_running = True

    def stop_ros_node(self):
        if self.ros_node is not None:
            self.ros_node.is_running = False

    def spin_ros_node(self, node):
        try:
            rclpy.spin(node)
        finally:
            node.destroy_node()

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    app = InterfaceApp()
    app.run()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is just an example. Publisher node sends increasing number every second and when we press start button, subscriber receives messages. Additionaly let me publisher node code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
 
from example_interfaces.msg import Int64
 
class RobotNewStationNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("robot_news_station")
        self.number_ = 0
        self.number_publisher_ = self.create_publisher(Int64, "robot_news", 10)
        self.number_timer_ = self.create_timer(1.0, self.publish_news)
        self.get_logger().info("Number publisher has been started.")

    def publish_news(self):
        msg = Int64()
        msg.data = self.number_
        self.number_publisher_.publish(msg)
 
def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = RobotNewStationNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()

 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```